# Skype keeps logging-out after every reboot

Tags: skype, ubuntu-18.04

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I have install Skype version 8.28.0.41 through snap. After successful login, my Skype is getting logged-out after every reboot of my system (See here):

[image: (See here)]

I tried installing different versions of Skype through different methods. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Also having this problem on Arch Linux, skypeforlinux-bin-stable version 8.58.0.93. Every time I start Skype, I briefly see my contacts list, and then I get logged out to the "Let's get started" screen. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the problem is the same on Ubuntu, but on Arch Linux I had to install `gnome-keyring` to make it remember my login.

After logging into Skype for the first time, `gnome-keyring` asked me to give a master password to create a new default keyring. Give it your regular login password to make the keyring unlock automatically when you log in.

Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=234135